# How to create records of a custom object?

Tags: custom-object, standard-objects, object, record

How to create records of a custom object?

I can create a record of any standard object type (for example `Account`) by going to `App Launcher` and selecting the  standard object type (for example `Account`).

I can not do the same with the custom object type, there is just no option for the record of such type in `App Launcher`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create tabs to see the 'objects' in App Launcher.

Go to Setup > Tabs > Custom Object Tabs > New